# Android Studio add Sounds Error

Tags: android, audio

I am trying to add a sound but there is the Error : `Cannot resolve method 'create(com.game.tobias.game.Explosion, int`' Why int ?

Code:

```
MediaPlayer explosion;
explosion = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mpExplosion)
explosion.start();
```

Comment: this method is running inside an activity?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getApplicationContext()` to get the context:

```
MediaPlayer explosion;
explosion = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.mpExplosion)
explosion.start();
```